# Find & Replace with a wildcard in Xcode 4

Tags: regex, xcode4, replace

I'm trying to find all instances of text inside "" marks with a semi-colon directly after them, and replace the text inside the "" marks. So, for example:

```
"FirstKey" = "First value";
"SecondKey" = "Second value";
"ThirdKey" = "Third value";
```

Would find only those values after the equals signs, and could replace them all (with a single string) at once, like so:

```
"FirstKey" = "BLAH";
"SecondKey" = "BLAH";
"ThirdKey" = "BLAH";
```

How can I do this? I found some stuff referring to regular expressions in Xcode 3, but such functionality seems either gone or hidden in Xcode 4.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Regular expression replace is still available in Xcode 4. Use "Replace" and set style to "Regular Expression", use `"([^"]*)";` as pattern and replace with `"BLAH";`.

Comment: Aha! The Find Options were very craftily hidden inside the little magnifying glass besides the search field. Thanks!

Comment: What if you wanted "First BLAH"; "Second BLAH"; etc?

Comment: @indiekiduk as the pattern in my answer have a capture group for the content inside the second quote you should be able to use the replace string `"\1 BLAH";`