# Replace defined code in Xcode with actual code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

For example, if I have `#define example(__thing__)  [__thing__ doSomeStuff]`.

Later in the code, I write `example(a)` the compiler will treat it as `[a doSomeStuff]`.

However, is there a way for it to replace it in the source code for debugging purposes? I want every occurrence of `example(a)` to be replaced with `[a doSomeStuff]`. Since the actual defined things are much longer it would be a lot easier to debug if I could see what the actual code is.

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode, go to Product menu -> Perform Action -> Preprocess "".

This will give you the preprocessed output of your source. You can then see how your code actually looks when compiled. This won't help for debugging, but you could always copy the appropriate sections and paste it into the actual code for debugging purposes. Otherwise, it at least lets you see the preprocessed code. I think this is the closest you're going to get to what you want.

Comment: Oh, so there is no way to preprocess only a certain section of the code?

Comment: @codenamepenryn I don't know a way to preprocess just a section of the code, no. This will preprocess the whole file, including imported header files. So the preprocessed file is often rather long. But your code should generally be toward the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Try, CMD + F and then there will be a small box that says 'Replace' then find `example(a)` and replace with `[a doSomeStuff]`. If you then want to undo, just reverse the fields.

**UPDATE:** If you are looking for batch find and replace, consider using wildcards: [Find & Replace with a wildcard in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471428/find-replace-with-a-wildcard-in-xcode-4)

Comment: The actual defines are a lot more complicated so a simple replace won't work.

Comment: This will only work for instances where he is calling `example` with `a`.  If somewhere else in the code he sends a different variable (like `example(b)`), he'll need to do a find-replace for `example(b)` as well.  And so on for how ever many variables he is sending.

Comment: Then try to comment the defines and then write what you want. Then undo by commenting the other set. If that still doesnt work, then try creating an Xcode template

Comment: This answer is not what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @Gavin: I think this approach will produce the result that the OP is looking for, it's just a rather messy way of doing it.

Comment: @GeneralMike As the OP said, his actual `#define`s are more complicated than what he posted, so a simple find and replace won't work. A simple find and replace wouldn't handle, for example, the following: `#define example(a) if (a) a++;`, because the `a` parameter is used twice. Find and replace is not able to handle complicated `#define`s.